# What kind of vegetable plant is this?

Tags: identification, vegetables

[image]

Hello! My daughter and I planted a veggie garden together and cannot remember what we planted! We have no idea what this is?  Anyone know?

Comment: Lesson learned for next time - add a label with the name of the vegetable so you don't have to remember

Answer (score 3):

This is a very good-looking kind of the kale family.

It could be unattended brussels sprouts, because of the numerous ramifications bearing flowers.

Comment: I was thinking broccoli but this is the prettiest bolting broccoli ever.